# VHDL simulation error: "delta count overflow"

Tags: vhdl

> run 50 ns
>   **#KERNEL: stopped at delta: 5000 at time 10 ns.
>
>   #KERNEL: Error: KERNEL_0160 Delta count overflow. Increase the iteration limit using -i argument for asim or the matching entry in
>   simulation preferences.
>
>   #Error: Fatal error occurred during simulation.**

Where I am wrong?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
entity funct is
    port(x: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 1);
    y: out std_logic);
end funct;

architecture funct of funct is
    signal r, s, q : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";
begin
    process
    begin
        wait on x, q;
        r(2) <= not(q(0)) or (not(q(1)) and x(2) and not(x(1)));
        r(1) <= q(2) and not(x(2));
        r(0) <= not(q(1)) and q(0) and x(1);
        s(2) <= q(1) and x(2);
        s(1) <= not(q(2)) and q(0) and not(x(2));
        s(0) <= not(q(2)) and not(q(1)) and not(q(0)) and x(2);
    end process; 

    y <= q(2) and not(q(1)) and q(0);

    process
    begin
        wait on r, s;
        q(0) <= s(0) or (not(r(0)) and q(0)); 
        q(1) <= s(1) or (not(r(1)) and q(1));   
        q(2) <= s(2) or (not(r(2)) and q(2));
    end process;
end funct;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two processes triggers each other in a circular way:

- When `x` initially changes, it triggers the first process,
- `r` and `s` are generated by the first process,
- these are used in the `wait` for the second process,
- which then generates `q`,
- what is use in the `wait` of the first process

An so the execution of first, second, first, ... processes continues without increment of time, but with increment of the delta counter, until the delta counter limit is reached, and you get the error you see.

To address this, you need to correct the combinational logic to avoid the internal loop.

Also, the process with wait on signals similar like:

```
process is
begin
  ... 
  wait on {signals};
end process;
```

is usually written like:

```
process ({signals}) is
begin
  ...
end process;
```

If purely combinational logic is written in the process, then you can actually skip making a process, so your code can be written like:

```
r(2) <= not(q(0)) or (not(q(1)) and x(2) and not(x(1)));
r(1) <= q(2) and not(x(2));
r(0) <= not(q(1)) and q(0) and x(1);
s(2) <= q(1) and x(2);
s(1) <= not(q(2)) and q(0) and not(x(2));
s(0) <= not(q(2)) and not(q(1)) and not(q(0)) and x(2);

y <= q(2) and not(q(1)) and q(0);

q(0) <= s(0) or (not(r(0)) and q(0)); 
q(1) <= s(1) or (not(r(1)) and q(1));   
q(2) <= s(2) or (not(r(2)) and q(2));
```

And writing the code this way, clearly reveals the combinational loop from `q(0)` to `r(0)` to `q(0)`.